# Как изменить value у progress?

Tags: javascript, события

Почему value изменяется но школа прогресса не двигается?

```js
let progress = document.querySelector('.progress1');

progress.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    progressValue += 10;
})
```

```html
<section>
            <p><b>Task 20.</b></p>
            <p> Дан элемент progress. Напишите фукнцию t20 которая увеличивает его value на 1 при каждом событии
                mousemove внутри progress.
            </p>
            <progress class='progress1' max="100" value="10">
                Загружено на <span id="value">25</span>%
            </progress>
            <div class="out-19">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: а почему она должна двигаться? сейчас вон вооббще ошибка незнакомой переменной. так что код вообще не рабочий

Answer (score 0):

В обработчиках событий к элементу на котором оно происходит можно обращаться по разному, либо через переменную объявленную снаружи - не очень красиво и не очень правильно, либо через `event.target` - применяется чаще, либо, если это не стрелочная функция через `this`, согласно [статьи Ильи Кантора](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events) это же значение можно получить через `event.currentTarget` - по сути это ссылка на элемент чей обработчик собитий задействован, т.е. если бы мы навесили `mousemove` на `body` то по перемещению над `прогресс баром` мы бы получили `body` в `event.currentTarget` и `.progress1` в `event.target` как на элементе инициализирующем событие.

*Иногда, использование обоих этих таргетов полезно, например, в работе с модальным окном, находящимся в полупрозрачной положке `wrapper` застилающий фон. Если `event.currentTarget` === `event.target` то событие произошло не на модальном окне, при условии что обработчик на `wrapper`, таким образом мы можем например закрыть модальное окно.*

```js
const wrapper=document.querySelector('.wrapper')
wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.clear()
  console.log(
    `currentTarget: ${event.currentTarget.className} target: ${event.target.className}`
  )
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="modal"></modal>
</div>
```

Стрелочные функции сами по себе имеют право на существование, но у них есть отличие от обычных функций и это отличие нужно учитывать при написании кода.

```js
let progress = document.querySelector('.progress1');

progress.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    this.value += 10;
})
```

```html
<section>
    <p><b>Task 20.</b></p>
    <p> Дан элемент progress. Напишите фукнцию t20 которая увеличивает его value на 1 при каждом событии
        mousemove внутри progress.
    </p>
    <progress class='progress1' max="100" value="10">
        Загружено на <span id="value">25</span>%
    </progress>
    <div class="out-19">
    </div>
</section>
```

Решение, какой вариант обращения к прогресс бару использовать остается за Вами, но чем чаще Вы будете смотреть на то как пишут код в разных библиотеках, или просто профессионалы, тем меньше у Вас будет вопросов как правильно писать код. И разумеется опыт чтения (с пониманием) ошибок, позволит Вам преодолевать такие ошибки как эта.